Is it possible to switch colour of "grep" output?
On my WSL, I have quite a large list of information, containing amongst others the "level" value, which can be 1 or 2.
In order to see the levels, I'm using the following combination of commands:
Prompt>alias grep
alias grep='grep -a --color=auto'

Prompt>grep "\"Lv\"\:[0-9]*," 2024-10-04.log

This latter command indeed gives the output I'm looking for, as you can see here:

The problem is: I'm facing hundreds of entries like this and I want to see in an easy way the places where the level changes from one to two and back and forth.
In order to achieve this, some colouring scheme needs to be followed (I guess), which is determined by the environment variable GREP_COLORS (again, I guess), but I don't understand the syntax of that variable, as you can see here:
Prompt>echo $GREP_COLORS
ms=01;31:mc=01;31:sl=:cx=:fn=93:ln=32:bn=32:se=36

Is there some way I can edit this variable and ask for alternating colours for different grep outputs?
Thanks in advance
P.s. some info on my environment:
Prompt>cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"


did you look at the man page? It specifically states that it's the GREP_COLORS envvar that controls the colors (or the deprecated GREP_COLOR, anyway no need to guess), and explains the syntax. Is there something in specific there you're missing? https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html#ENVIRONMENT

as for alternating colors between consecutive matches, based on the man page, the answer seems to be "no"

@ilkkachu: thanks for the quick reply. I did had a glance to the man GREP_COLORS but I didn't understand it immediately. You say that alternating colours seems not to be possible, but what about different colours per output (like red for "Lv:1", green for "Lv:2", yellow for "Lv:3", ...), I mean different colours for different results of the regular expression ±"Lv:[0-9]*".

I just glanced at the man page (esp. the mt/ms/mc items), and there doesn't seem to be anything there about multiple different colors for different patterns, just for matches on a selected line vs. on a context line (which is marginal in itself since it would seem to mean lines adjacent to non-matching lines when -v is used). I suppose one could cook something up with awk or Perl...

Here's an extremely c****y Perl one-liner that highlights matches of /"Lv":\d+/ alternating between blue and magenta on every matching line:
perl -pe 'BEGIN { $c = 34; $pattern = q("Lv":\d+) }
          if (/$pattern/) { s#$pattern#\33[01;${c}m$&\33[0m#; $c ^=  1; }'

It just manually prints the color escapes (with no regard for terminfo or anything like that), changing the color with xor after each match.
Sample output:

